# Как настроить CMake в IDE CLion от JetBrains

Tags: c++, ide, cmake

Добрый день друзья!
Недавно скачал и установил IDE от JetBrains CLion для С/С++, установил CMake, MinGW, но у меня все равно отображается ошибка что нету компилятора C.

[image: Screen CLion]

Помогите пожалуйста настроить IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Нажимаете <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, пишете `Toolchains`. В появившемся окошке прописываете пути к `cmake` и компилятору.

Comment: У меня пути все настроенны, но ошибка все равно есть. Я же скрин выложил, там отмеченно, что есть CMake v 3.1.1

Comment: возможно, пути неправильно прописаны, а возможно, это потому что mingw.
с обычной консоли cmake/gcc запускается?

Comment: В консоли через gcc компилится, только с cmake не пробовал, с ним еще не доводилось работать, внутри IDE в терминале компилирую вручную проекты gcc main.c -o main и тд. так работает, но хочется через IDE автоматически работать, нафиг она мне тогда нужна я и в блокноте с таким успехом могу кодить.

Comment: `CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM-NOTFOUND` `CMAKE_SH-NOTFOUND` ошибки во вкладке Cache

Comment: на линуксе заводиться с пол пинка. А на винде... Может им (JetBrains) написать в поддержку?

Comment: Писал уже, не отвечают, но спасибо за содействие!

Answer (score 1):

[image: MinGW]

Скачиваешь пакеты к примеру как на скриншоте.
Указываешь путь к самой папке компилятора.
Единственное что замечал это, что COMODO Firewall блокировал доступ... 
Возможно он не единственный.

Answer (score 1):

у меня стоит linux mint 17.3 cinnamon была та же проблема...
Решил ее таким путем
 Скачал  CMake нужной версии с оф сайта и закинул его в папку Clion/bin/cmake (Clion его сразу подтянул но осталась проблема с GDB)
Вся суть в том что linux mint 17.3 основан на убунте 14.04 если не ошибаюсь, а там еще старая версия GDB, исправил тем что апгрейдил GDB до 7.8 после ребут и все заработало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]